# How can I view the stack used by `pushd` and `popd`?

Tags: shell-builtin, pushd

I would like to use the recently accessed directories list for logging purposes.

Is the directory stack as used by `pushd` and `popd` stored somewhere, perhaps as a list of folders in a text file? If so, where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it could be in...

```sh
printf %s\\n "${DIRSTACK[@]}" >this_text_file
```

Answer (score 9):

## `dirs`

is the shell builtin you're looking for, see [the man page for bash's implementation](https://ss64.com/bash/dirs.html):

> Display the list of currently remembered directories.
>
> Syntax
>
> > `dirs [+N | -N] [-clpv]`

Answer (score 1):

No, it's just in memory. the source code lies in `bash-4.4/builtins/pushd.def: popd_builtin`